# How to migrate from karma to jest in Angular 17

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have recently found out about [this](https://blog.angular.io/moving-angular-cli-to-jest-and-web-test-runner-ef85ef69ceca) blog post about the experimental jest support since angular 16. Based on what I understood I did the following steps:

Installed the following dependencies:

```
npm install jest --save-dev
npm install jest-environment-jsdom --save-dev
npm install @types/jest --save-dev
```

In `angular.json` changed:

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
....
```

to:

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
...
```

And in `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` in `compilerOptions.type` i replaced `jasmine` with `jest`.

However Running the a spec file would result in the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/<USER>/Developer/<DIR>/<PROJECT>/src/app/screens/test-component/test-component.component.spec.ts: Missing semicolon. (7:15)

       5 |
       6 | describe('CalibrateKeysComponent', () => {
    >  7 |   let component: TestComponent;
         |                ^
       8 |   let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
       9 |
      10 |   beforeEach(() => {

      at constructor (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error.ts:81:19)
      at Parser.toParseError [as raise] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1487:19)
      at Parser.raise [as semicolon] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.ts:141:10)
      at Parser.semicolon [as parseVarStatement] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1201:10)
      at Parser.parseVarStatement [as parseStatementContent] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:553:21)
      at Parser.parseStatementContent [as parseStatementLike] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:416:17)
      at Parser.parseStatementLike [as parseStatementListItem] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:365:17)
      at Parser.parseStatementListItem [as parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1394:16)
      at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody [as parseBlockBody] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1367:10)
      at Parser.parseBlockBody [as parseBlock] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1335:10)
      at Parser.parseBlock [as parseFunctionBody] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2586:24)
      at Parser.parseFunctionBody [as parseArrowExpression] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2529:10)
      at Parser.parseArrowExpression [as parseParenAndDistinguishExpression] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1826:12)
      at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression [as parseExprAtom] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1165:21)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom [as parseExprSubscripts] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:705:23)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts [as parseUpdate] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:682:21)
      at Parser.parseUpdate [as parseMaybeUnary] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:644:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary [as parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:382:14)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate [as parseExprOps] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:394:23)
      at Parser.parseExprOps [as parseMaybeConditional] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:349:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional [as parseMaybeAssign] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:289:21)
      at parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:243:12)
      at Parser.callback [as allowInAnd] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:3139:12)
      at Parser.allowInAnd [as parseMaybeAssignAllowIn] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:242:17)
      at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn [as parseExprListItem] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2752:18)
      at Parser.parseExprListItem [as parseCallExpressionArguments] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1039:14)
      at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments [as parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:881:29)
      at Parser.parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead [as parseSubscript] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:770:19)
      at Parser.parseSubscript [as parseSubscripts] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:726:19)
      at Parser.parseSubscripts [as parseExprSubscripts] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:711:17)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts [as parseUpdate] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:682:21)
      at Parser.parseUpdate [as parseMaybeUnary] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:644:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary [as parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:382:14)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate [as parseExprOps] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:394:23)
      at Parser.parseExprOps [as parseMaybeConditional] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:349:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional [as parseMaybeAssign] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:289:21)
      at Parser.parseMaybeAssign [as parseExpressionBase] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:212:23)
      at parseExpressionBase (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:203:39)
      at Parser.callback [as allowInAnd] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:3134:16)
      at Parser.allowInAnd [as parseExpression] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:203:17)
      at Parser.parseExpression [as parseStatementContent] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:644:23)
      at Parser.parseStatementContent [as parseStatementLike] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:416:17)
      at Parser.parseStatementLike [as parseModuleItem] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:353:17)
      at Parser.parseModuleItem [as parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1393:16)
      at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody [as parseBlockBody] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1367:10)
      at Parser.parseBlockBody [as parseProgram] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:212:10)
      at Parser.parseProgram [as parseTopLevel] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:194:25)
      at Parser.parseTopLevel [as parse] (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/index.ts:45:10)
      at parse (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:66:38)
      at parser (node_modules/@babel/core/src/parser/index.ts:28:19)
          at parser.next (<anonymous>)
      at normalizeFile (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/normalize-file.ts:50:24)
          at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
      at run (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:39:36)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
      at transform (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
      at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
      at sync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
      at fn (node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:99:14)
      at transformSync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:545:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)
```

My question is how this migration from karma to jasmine should be done with respect to angulars experimental support of jest? Or what did I miss in my steps?